# How can I set up complex jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, htmlelements

I have a html and jquery code. I am able to delete first `li` child of `ul` element. The problem is that I can delete only once and just one element. I want to make in a way that user can delete the element every time the user clicks a button.

I don't want to have any limits. or how can I set up limits?

Here is my markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>List 2:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
```

and JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("ul li:first").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you re-word the question? it is difficult to undersdtand

Comment: replace `.hide` to `.remove`;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the `li` element on every button click, you should be using `remove()` instead of `hide()` `hide()` only changes the visibility of the element, it does not remove it and the next button click will mark the *same* element as hidden (having no net effect). See the documentation:  [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("ul li:first").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>List 2:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button id="myBtn">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because when you use `hide()`

It only hides to element, it is still there. So when you refer to the first of the list it tries to hide() the one which is already hidden.

I think what you mean to do is remove the first one and then if you do the function again, it removes the next one.

Try `remove()`

Which removes the element.

So

```
$("button").click(function (){ $("ul li:first").remove(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

you said you want to delete then you can use remove like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("ul li:first-child").remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

*First off,* the `:first` selector **Selects the first matched element**.
You're looking for `:first-child Selector` which **Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.** 
This is why when combined with hide(), only works once.

Next, **hide()** is the CSS equivalent to `"display", "none"`
If you want refer to the new first child after each removal try using **remove()**.
This will permanently remove the child from the DOM and allow your code to refer to the newest li element.

- Coffee
- Milk
- Tea

List 2:

- Coffee
- Milk
- Tea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("ul li:first-child").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an another solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        //$("ul li:first").hide();
        $('ul li:visible:first').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>List 2:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button id="myBtn">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `:visible` selector, if you wish to hide and not delete it. This will search all visible `li`s only.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("ul li:visible:first").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>List 2:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button id="myBtn">Hide</button>
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Kindly share what is missing in the answer, so everyone can learn.

Comment: They never upvote for good answer, but downvote everywhere @Rajesh